# How to use await to fetch the latest values inside the build method | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-streambuilder

As you might know that usually we use StreamBuilders and FutureBuilders to show a widget based upon the future values.

e.g., Lets say `await A() -> gives Future<bool>`

Now, I can use a FutureBuilder inside by build such that:

```
Widget build() {
 FutureBuilder(
  future: A()
  builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.data.hasValue ? Text(snapshot.data) : Loading()
 )
}
```

Now, this all works but what If I'm inside my build and I want to decide If I want to invoke a function or not based on what A() returns. In short, I do NOT want to render a widget but just want the value from the respective method.

Since, FutureBuilders and StreamBuilders have to have some sort of return statement (something that returns a widget). How to overcome this problem ?

Right now, I have called this method in the start, put its value inside a stream and using stream.value where ever I need to use it. However, it is not the most reliable thing to do as my stream might not have been populated when .value runs

Answer (score 0):

FutureBuilder is used to handle  `asynchronous` calls that return the data you want to display.

To work around with future methods which needs to be await as it's asynchronous.

let's say you have a method which returns future :

```
 Future<List<String>> getStringList() async {
    try {
      return ['hyden', 'ponting', 'jalal', 'kholi'];
     
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

To handle this future method you can simply do :

```
getStringList.then((value){
       do(value)
   }else{
       handle(exception)
 });
```

or,

```
 var res = await getStringList(); 

 if(res){ //do }
        else{ //handle}
```

Comment: The only limitation with this approach is that you cannot use "await" everywhere, especially inside the build. Even if I specify this method inside my bloc, it will return Future<bool> which is again not usable inside the build method.

Comment: what exactly you need to do with the method? can you please elaborate more? i think i can help